# Can I preserve a modally presented view controller when setting the root view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I have three view controllers. On the first one, I tap a button and present the second view controller modally. On the second one, I tap a button and store the presenting view controller (first), then set the third view controller as the root view controller. Finally, I have a button on the third view controller that grabs the stored controller and sets that as the root view controller.

When I restore the first view controller, I find that its `presentedViewController` property is nil. I wonder if I can preserve the navigation stack and have the modal presented when I restore the first view controller?

In this example I'm storing the view controller inside AppDelegate for simplicity.

Code:

```
FirstViewController.swift

    @IBAction func presentViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondVC", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second")
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

```
SecondViewController.swift

    @IBAction func secondButtonCLick(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.savedVC = presentingViewController

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Third", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdVC")

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = controller
    }
```

```
ThirdViewController.swift

    @IBAction func thirdBtnTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let rootVC = appDelegate.savedVC
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootVC
    }
```

Comment: well, ur 1st ViewController never had a `presentedViewController `. `presentedViewController ` is supposed to indicate the view that presented it while your 1st ViewController was never presented.

Comment: @AppleCiderGuy Sorry, I meant presentedViewController. Fixed

Comment: i was talking about `presentedViewController ` as well. just copy pasted the var and thus the typo. ;)

Comment: Swapping around `.rootViewController` is really not a great practice to begin with. But, as you've seen, no... when you remove the VC from the hierarchy, any VC it has presented will be dismissed. If you *really* want to go that route, you'll need to add a function when you "re-set" FirstVC as the root to have it again present your modal VC. Does it really need to be a **modally presented** VC? Another (perhaps better) option would be to add SecondVC as a child and show its view on top of FirstVC's contents.

Comment: @AppleCiderGuy I'm confused, this is from Apple's docs on `presentedViewController`: "When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or implicitly) using the present(_:animated:completion:) method, the view controller that called the method has this property set to the view controller that it presented." So `FirstViewController`'s `presentedViewController` should be `SecondViewController`

Comment: @DonMag Unfortunately this rootViewController switching behaviour is coming from a framework that I have to use. We know that using `pushViewController` onto a navigation controller works, but we want to have it animated like a modal (coming from the bottom up) and it'd be nice to keep things simple ;)

Comment: @jcharch sorry I confused `presenting` and `presented`