# Setting window.rootViewController with a presented view controller on top shows a blank screen (iOS 12)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

**EDIT**: I think the potential problem is how the VC is being presented:

```
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

This leads to the `UITransitionView` and my navigation controller to be at the same level of the view hierarchy, so when I save the `window.rootViewController` I am saving the wrong one to persist. If I take out this line, things work as expected. However, I do need it to be `overCurrentContext` or `overFullScreen` because I  need the presented view to be translucent and show the view underneath.

---

I have a problem, present on iOS 12 but not 13, where my application is not showing my root view controller after setting it.

There is a view controller presented on top of another view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller.

At one point the following logic (more or less) is executed:

```
var savedVC: UIViewController

...

savedVc = window.rootViewController
window.rootViewController = <...>

<some business logic here...>

UIWindow window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.rootViewController = savedVc
```

At the end of this, my view hierarchy only contains the presented view controller. 
[image]

However the navigation controller is still the rootViewController of the window!

[image]

And if I dismiss this view controller the application shows me a blank screen. On iOS 13 this is working as expected, I can see the controller under the presented one.

Comment: Actually on 13 the presented view controller goes away after setting the rootviewcontroller (see my previous question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956631/can-i-preserve-a-modally-presented-view-controller-when-setting-the-root-view-co) but that is neither here nor there, I can preserve the presented view in a variable and present it again once the `window.rootViewController` is re-set

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the navigation controller 
try this out

```
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as! NewViewController
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```